# Operator Overloading for vector holding complex numbers

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<complex>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

vector<complex<double> > Compute_wn(int n);
int main()

{
    Compute_wn(8);
    return 0;
}


vector<complex<double> > Compute_wn(int n)
{
    vector<complex<double> > V[n];
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        V[i] = complex<double>(cos(2.0*M_PI*double(i)/double(n)),sin(2.0*M_PI*double(i)/double(n)));
        cout<<V[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
```

I am new to C++. When I compile this code the error I get is that error: no viable overloaded '='.
(`V[i] = complex<double>(cos(2.0*M_PI*double(i)/double(n)),sin(2.0*M_PI*double(i)/double(n)));`) I don't understand how I need to overload the operator '=' for a vector of complex numbers of type double. As I understand that vector is a vector of complex numbers I should be able to directly assign to V[I].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing array and vector syntax, and here's the culprit:

```
vector<complex<double>> V[n];
```

This defines an *array of size `n`* of `vector<complex<double>>`. Since `n` is not a compile-time constant, this shouldn't be allowed, but some compilers accept it as a non-standard extension. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) for discussion.

This means that `V[i]` is actually a `vector<complex<double>>`, not a `complex<double>`, and that's why you can't assign a `complex<double>` to it.

The fix is to correctly initialize your vector:

```
vector<complex<double>> V;
V.resize(n);
```

**Note:** you're currently not returning anything from your function which is declared to return `vector<complex<double>>`, which will cause a bad case of Undefined-Behavior-related woes. Did you mean to `return V;`?